# Converting Large Data Table To Use Partitions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a single MSSQL 2017 Standard table, let's call it `myTable`, with data going back to 2015, containing 206.4 million rows. Once INSERTed by the application, these rows are never modified or deleted. The table is actively collecting data, 24/7.

My goal is to reduce the data in this table to only the most recent full 6 months plus current month, into monthly-based partitions for easy monthly pruning. `myTable.dateCreated` would determine which partition the data ultimately resides.

*(Unrelated, but mentioning in case it ends up being relevant: I have an existing application that replicates all data that gets stored in `myTable` out to a data warehouse for long term storage every 15 minutes; the main application is able to query `myTable` for recent data and the data warehouse for older data as needed.)*

Because I want to prune the oldest one month worth of data out of `myTable` each time a new month starts, **partitioning** `myTable` by month makes the most sense - I can simply SWITCH the oldest partition to a staging table, then truncate that staging table without causing downtime or performance on the main table.

**I've come up with the following plan, and my questions are simple: Is this the best way to approach this task, and will it keep downtime/performance degradation to a minimum?**

1. Create a new table, `myTable_pending`, with the same exact table structure as `myTable`, EXCEPT that it will have a total of 7 monthly partitions (6 months retention plus current month) configured;
2. In one complete step: rename `myTable` to `myTable_transfer`, and rename `myTable_pending` to `myTable`.  This should have the net effect of allowing incoming data to continue being stored, but now it will be in a partition for the month of 2023-01;

Step 3 is where I need advice... which of the following might be best to get the remaining 6mos + current data back into the now-partitioned `myTable`, or are there additional options I should consider?

**OPTION 1:** Run a Bulk Insert of just the most recent 6 months of data from `myTable_transfer` back into `myTable`, causing the data to end up in the correct partitions in the process (with the understanding that this may still take some time, but not as long as a bunch of INSERTs that would end up chewing on the transaction log);

**OPTION 2:** Run a DELETE against `myTable_transfer`, getting rid of all data except the most recent full 6 months + current, and then set up and apply partitions on THIS table, that would then cause SQL Server to reorganize the data into those partitions, but without affecting access or performance on `myTable`, after which I could just SWITCH the partitions from `myTable_transfer` into `myTable` for immediate access; (related issue: since `myTable` is still collecting current data, and `myTable_transfer` will contain data from the current month as well, can the current month partitions be merged?)

OPTION 3: Any other way to do this, so that `myTable` ends up with 6 months worth of data, properly partitioned, without significant downtime?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Partition-level `TRUNCATE` is available in SQL 2016+ so you don't need to bother with `SWITCH` to prune.

Comment: SQL Server 2017 Standard. Nice to know we won't need a staging table to do the truncate anymore!

Comment: How may rows for the last 6 months?

Comment: just over 20M for 6 months, higher if I include 6 mos + current, but this is in the ballpark.

Comment: If it were me, I'd be lazy and make the current table the oldest partition and let it roll off in 7 months time. But if your table only has 20M rows in it, you can rebuild the table on the same partition scheme as the live table and then swap partitions in.

Comment: @BenThul, so to be clear, my Option Two is what you're suggesting? And if so, with both the source `myTable_transfer` table and `myTable` both having a partition for the current month, with both having records in that partition, will it be possible to merge them (if not, at least it's not a ton of records to INSERT INTO from source to destination, I guess...)

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't to any delete as phase one of that plan. Also, if you have an environment that you can test it on, it might be worth exploring not doing the 'create new table, rename' dance and instead rebuild the table as it exists now on the partition scheme. I appreciate that you're on Standard Edition and so it won't be an online operation. But at 20M rows, I wouldn't expect that index rebuild to take very long. So if you can tolerate a bit of blocking on that table (or, alternatively, coordinated app downtime), that might be easier.

Comment: And in re: being able to do partition work if both the source and target have data in their respective partitions, the answer is "no"; you'll have to evacuate one or the other of them if you want to do a partition switch.

Comment: Hold - I think I had a fundamental misunderstanding. The 20M number is for the targeted retention of 6 months; current data is 200M+ rows. Given that, I *would* purge down to the targeted retention first (or create your partition scheme with the first boundary sufficiently in the future so that you don't have to and it'll just age out naturally).

Answer (score 0):

We ended up revising our solution, since the original table was replicated to a data warehouse anyway, we simply renamed the table and created a new one with partitioning to start collecting new data from the rename point. This provided the least amount of downtime, the fastest schema changes, and gave us the partitioning we needed to maintain the table efficiently going forward.